# I withdrew cash from U.S. ATM (not U.S. bank card) and put it into U.S. bank. Is it taxable income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, cash, atm

I'm filling tax return forms 1040NR-EZ, 540NR-short for non-resident (I was exchange visitor in U.S.).

When I was in U.S., I withdrew cash from an ATM using a card from an account of mine at a non-US bank, and then put it into my U.S. bank account. I withdrew and then put in my U.S. bank $2000 totally.

Is it an income that I should declare somehow in forms mentioned above?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is YOUR non-US bank account, not someone else's?

Comment: Yes, if the two accounts are yours I don't see a problem. If the non-US card was someone else's... that may mean you've received income.

Answer (score 11):

You normally wouldn't pay income taxes on money that isn't income. Transferring money or withdrawing it from a bank isn't an income generating event. I think it is very doubtful that you would need to claim that on income tax forms.

Comment: Agreed, this just seems to be like transferring from one bank account to another... unless the `not U.S. bank card` was a pre-paid card sent to the poster as payment (income).

Comment: @PeterK. Even if that were the case, the receipt of the pre-paid card is the income-generating event, not the transfer into a US bank account.

Comment: @DJClayworth Understood. If that is what has happened, though, it needs to be reported as income (not just the act of depositing it, as you point out).

Comment: No, I used my own, regular credit card of not U.S. bank. So, I just "transferred" money from my not U.S. bank to U.S. bank.

Comment: I'm actually curious about that, @DJClayworth.  I understand the receipt of a check as _not_ being the income generating event, but the depositing of the check (which then pulls money into my account from theirs).  Is this different because the prepaid card is give-or-take valid currency in and of itself?  Or is my understanding wrong...

Comment: A cheque is an 'order to pay'. If you never cash the cheque no money is transferred. However with a prepaid card the money has been paid to the card account, which is now yours. I guess if you never used the card you might argue that the value isn't income. But really all I meant to say was that if you spent the money on the card in ways other than transferring it to your account it is still income.

Comment: @joe *if* the check is taxable income (which this OPs case apparently isn't) it is reportable *when* you receive the check or it is "made available" to you, even if you haven't cashed it. See http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000170550 .